# Mongo shell not open in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: mongodb

> MongoDB shell version v3.4.7
>
> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
>
> 2018-05-10T10:54:49.810+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to
> 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
>
> 2018-05-10T10:54:49.810+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't
> connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13 @(connect):1:6
>
> exception: connect failed

Comment: The `mongod` server is not running. Ubuntu 17 is a development branch anyway. There is no official support on the platform so it would be recommended that you use a stable OS which is actually supported by MongoDB. But bottom line is your server is not running and installing from unsupported packages on an unsupported OS will do that.

Comment: There's also literally hundreds of resources on correct installation instructions out there. If you actually tried anything before it would be wise to indicate what you did. Otherwise we can't do much more than point you to the existing documentation and tell you to follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything check if Mongo is running

ps -aux | grep mongo 
or

/etc/init.d/mongodb status     # give MongoDB version < 2.6
   /etc/init.d/mongod status      # for MongoDB version >= 2.6

or

service mongod status (you need to be root or to prefix it with sudo).

or

Mongo log file /var/log/mongo/mongo.log can give you valuable information